# Plugin license key is lost every time I update Craft CMS

Tags: plugins, license

I have licensed the Verbb Navigation plugin, but every time I update Craft I get a notice that the license needs attention. The key field on the Plugins page is empty after the update. Is this a bug, or is there another way to store the key so it will be saved after an update?

Comment: Odd... how are you updating/deploying Craft?

Comment: Update on a local dev machine via control panel, then deploy composer.json and run composer update on production machine.

Comment: We’re also deploying a project.yaml file from our local environment, where the plugin is not licensed. Could that be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

@Dalton I would say that's indeed the issue (using the project.yaml file), at least at first glance.

Every time you're pushing the project.yaml file to your server, it'll overwrite your server's project.yaml file. Because the plugin isn't licensed locally, you're basically removing the license each deploy.

Can you register the license locally, then push your project.yaml file? You'll notice locally, as soon as you enter a license key, the file will change to store this license key. Things should stay in sync from then on.